# Using Regular Expressions in R to change number formating

Tags: regex, r

In data frame `df` column `c1` has negative numerical values formatted like this:

> (1,000,000)

I would like to remove the parentheses from the negative values in `df$c1`, so as to return:

> -1,000,000

I am using the following command in R: `df$c1<-gsub('^\\($','-',gsub(',','',df$c1))`

But the output is not returning the desired effect.

How can I adjust the regular expression in this R command to return the proper formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it instead be:

```
df$c1<-sub('^\\(', '-' , sub('\\)$','',df$c1))
```

This removes leading left-parens, replacing them with minus signs, and removes trailing right-parens. Your version was insisting that the 'outer' pattern be exactly `(`, which I doubt would match any items,  and was removing commas using the 'inner' call. I changed to `sub` since there was only the desire to do this once for each element.

Comment: this command replaces the closing parentheses ')' but it does not replace the opening parentheses with a '-' negative sign. Perhaps there is some white space in the column I am applying this to and it is throwing it off?

Comment: Perhaps. How to proceed depends on how stringent you want the replacement test to be. You could just remove the `^` from the pattern and it would just replace the first left-paren with a minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub("\\((.+)\\)", "-\\1", "(1,000,000)")
# [1] "-1,000,000"
```